# Google Tag Manager / Google Analytics - multiple internal site searches and parameter cleaning of uris

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, query-string, site-search, google-site-search

I use Google Analytics to track the searches users do on my website. I have no query parameter for searches (nothing like `q=mykeyword`).
Therefore I use Google Tag Manager to send a "fake" value for the field `page` to Google Analytics with the following snippet:

```
function() {
  var regex = /^(\/[a-z]{0,2}\/live\/search)\/(.*)/;
  if(regex.test({{Page Path}})) {
    var res = regex.exec({{Page Path}});
    return res[1]+"?gaSearchLive=" + res[2];
  }
  return;
}
```

A typical URI used for searches is `/de/live/search/mykeyword?searchID=1234` or `/en/archive/search/mykeyword2?searchID=4567`.

My website differentiates between `live` and `archive` searches. Is there a way to separate those two kinds of search in a way that I can analyze them separately in Google Analytics?

How can I prevent query parameters from polluting my analysis?
In section `Behavior => Site Search => Pages` I see the following:

[image: pages with query parameters]

Is there a way to remove parameters like "searchID" / "page" etc. from the url? How do I need to modify my Google Tag Manager tag? Is it possible to overwrite the url sent to Google Analytics as I do already for the `page` field?

Answer (score 1):

I would use separate views for each. One that includes pages that start `/de/live/search` and one for `/de/archive/search`.

Then you could exclude the query parameters from your main reporting view in the view settings.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I excluded the parameters via view settings. Regarding separate views for live / archive searches: I find it very confusing, because I need to switch the views often. Is there no solution, creating different reports one for live / archive and add them to the `Site Search` menu? Or maybe via custom dashboard? I tried already but dashboards cannot display tables with more than one dimension... So I need to view every custom report itself instead of having a overview of all relevant searches...